# Warning when react virtualized column is subclassed

Tags: react-virtualized

When I inherit/subclass the 'Column' component, it throws `Warning: Failed prop type: Table only accepts children of type Column`

This is how I subclassed `Column`

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';
import * as RV from 'react-virtualized';

class Column extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <RVC.Column {...this.props} type="Column" />
        )
    }
}

Column.defaultProps = RV.Column.defaultProps;
Column.propTypes = RV.Column.propTypes;

export default Column;
```

It works very well but how can I avoid from that warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's any benefit to subclassing `Column`. I assume your real intent is to set default values or DRY up your project in which case, I'd suggest just using a factory-function for columns like so:

```
import { Column, Table } from 'react-virtualized'

export default function CustomColumn (columnProps) {
  const customProps = {
    // Set any default props here ...
  }

  return (
    <Column
      {...customProps}
      {...columnProps}          
    />
  )
}

function ExampleTable (tableProps) {
  return (
    <Table {...tableProps}>
      {CustomColumn({
        dataKey: 'foo',
        width: 100
      })}
      {CustomColumn({
        dataKey: 'bar',
        width: 100
      })}
    </Table>
  )
}
```

For what it's worth, I've done this on Production projects and it works nicely. If you think you have a strong use-case for subclassing `Column` though let me know and I will consider adding support for it.

Comment: I added a `CustomColumn` method as you suggested and easily implemented a proper `headerRenderer`. Thanks! However, there is another challenge that I'm facing now which is adding a custom button to column header to reset column sorting. I'm able to add a button to the header but I'm not sure how I can handle `onClick` event properly. For example, I can't disable `onHeaderClick` when that inner button is clicked. Ideally, I'd like to add a new props to table like onColumnRemoveSortClicked but not sure how to pass this props to the component rendered in column's `headerRenderer`

Comment: You can directly pass parameters (eg the `sort` callback) to your `headerRenderer` so I would suggest just having it call that method directly rather than use the `onHeaderClick`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you are not subclassing `RV.Column` at all, you are still subclassing `React.Component`, just that the name of your component is `Column`. React will still show the error because your self-defined `Column` !== `RVC.Column`.

Why do you want to subclass it in the first place? What does `type="Column"` do?